# How to save file from internet with PHP?

Tags: php

For example, I have a link "http://www.abcd.com/folder/1.flv" and I need save this file in my hard disk. I must do that by PHP, but my knowledge of PHP is little. Tell me please how I can do that.

Comment: file_get_contents and file_put_contents would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for smaller files, you can use file_get_contents with file_put_contents, but in this case, (because it is an flv), you may wish to use two files:

```
$rd = fopen("http://www.abcd.com/folder/1.flv", 'r');
$wt = fopen("<local path to write to>", "w");
// read a line from the url (8192 is a standard chunk size)
while( FALSE !== ( $ln = fread( $rd, 8192 ) ) )
{
    // write it locally
    fwrite( $wt, $ln );
    // rinse, repeat until file is done
}
fclose( $wt ); // close the local file.
fclose( $rd ); // close the remote stream
```

Comment: Being picky:  while($ln = fread(...)) should be while(false !== ($ln = ....))).  Also, I believe fread() requires a second parameter as does fopen.

Comment: You're right. I've been spending too much time in Python world.

Answer (score 2):

```
file_put_contents($localURL, file_get_contents($remoteURL));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using file_get_contents is all very well if you're scripting a download, but if you're referring to forcing a link on a page to be a download rather than embedded content when a user clicks on it, that's a very different thing. It's not clear from your question.

If it's the latter, you don't have to do this via PHP, you could set up a rule in your `.htaccess` file or your apache's `.conf` file, depending on the access you have at your disposal:

```
<FilesMatch "\.flv">
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    Header set Content-Type application/x-unknown
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
copy("http://www.abcd.com/folder/1.flv", "1.flv");
?>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy